# Connect-SPOService with OAuth2.0 fails in SharePoint Online PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication

anyone knows a solution for Connect-SPOService on SharePoint Online PowerShell.

So I need to use Set-SPOSite and before I can use that I need to do Connect-SPOService first.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Connect-SPOService
>>

cmdlet Connect-SPOService at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Url: https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/
Connect-SPOService : Could not authenticate to SharePoint Online https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/
using OAuth 2.0
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-SPOService
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-SPOService], AuthenticationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.AuthenticationException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoi
   nt.PowerShell.ConnectSPOService
```

The URL is not real, I login normally and did my 2FA with SMS but when I submit my 2FA it always fail. I tried it like 5 times just to be sure I was not putting the wrong code. I also tried using my App Password but it won't let me login with it.

Any known solution for this? My end goal is to edit my site to allow pages to be editted using SharePoint Designer. Would be a lot faster on editting ItemStyles for CQWP later

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/ -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried connecting to the '-admin' Url?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/connect-sposervice?view=sharepoint-ps

Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -credential admin@contoso.com

Comment: I tried that, now I'm getting `Connect-SPOService : Current site is not a tenant administration site.` which is weird cause I know I am a tenant administrator.

Comment: You are tenant admin but may be the site url you are providing is a not a tenant admin site.

Answer (score 0):

It seems credentials you are providing are somehow not working.Try below:

```
$username = "admin@contoso.sharepoint.com"
$password = "password"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential - 
argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/ -Credential 
$cred

 Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials $cred
```

Comment: i find it a little odd that you have to connect to the admin site before connecting to any other site / object.  does anyone have some background on this logic?

Comment: Suggesting another PowerShell module doesn't seem particular useful. OP seems to need to use SPO, not PnP.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove '/' at the end of url after test

*https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/*